# Sun and moon event differences

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Nintendo advertised that "certain events  will play out differently" in sun and moon. I know there are different pokemon between sun and moon, but my brother and I didn't see and events play out differently within the game. What are the events that played out differently between sun and moon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the version differences are listed [here](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/versionmisc.shtml).

Below I have included a summary of how they can play out differently. I have tried to avoid specific spoilers but you may wish to avoid reading on if that is a concern.

A twelve hour time difference:
If you play through the same part at the same time in real life, there is a night vs. day difference in game

Trials & Totem Pokemon

> Raticate and Ratatta vs Gumshoos and Yungoos in the first [Trial](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/islandtrials.shtml). Does not seem to occur in other Trials.

Summoning Altar (Late Game)

> As part of the main story you reach either the [Altar of the Sunne](http://www.serebii.net/pokearth/alola/altarofthesunne.shtml) or [Altar of the Moone](http://www.serebii.net/pokearth/alola/altarofthemoone.shtml) and will interact with the corresponding Legendary Pokemon. This affects a few cutscenes.

Unlocking Battle Styles

> Battling Kiawe or Mallow to unlock [Reverent Style](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/battlestyle.shtml). This is different than fighting them as part of the trials.